# How do I represent self-joined data in a RESTful API

Tags: rest, restful-architecture, self-join

I have products and categories represented by a REST API.
Products are children of categories i.e. `/categories/{category_id}/products/{product_id}`

Each category can also be child of another category. E.g: Transport -> Cars -> Sports cars -> Aston Martins.

How would I go about representing this RESTfully?

So far I have only come up with:   `/categories/{category_id}/categories/{category_id}/categories/{category_id}/`...
but I don't like how big the URI becomes assuming I can have many levels of subcategory.

Comment: Do you really need the full path? Isn't {category_id} unique for all categories?

Comment: @alex Yes you are right, but I was under the assumption that I should always maintain child/parent relationships in the URI

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to use a really long URL to uniquely identify a vehicle. Can a truck and a car have the same id? Can a Toyota and a Ford car have the same id?

Transport -> Cars -> Sports cars -> Aston Martins

could be as easy as:

```
transports/{id-of-a-particular-Aston-Martin}
```

or:

```
transports/{id-of-a-particular-truck}
```

or if you're viewing a filtered down collection based on some criteria:

```
transports/?body_style={id for sports car}&make={id for Aston Martin}
```

The fact that this vehicle is an Aston Martin, a car and a Sport Car doesn't have to be reflected in the URL.